# NSFont text size with variables: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0X3)

Tags: objective-c, nsfont

I'm keep getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I change this code from

```
label.font      = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:(80)];
```

to

```
label.font      = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:*(((messageSize)))];
```

The messageSize is set as a double like this.

```
double  *messageSize;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk is the symbol for a pointer, that's wrong.
A double is a simple scalar type.

```
double  messageSize;
```

And you can omit all parentheses.

```
label.font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:messageSize];
```

PS: Actually the expected type of `systemFontOfSize` is `CGFloat` which is a `float` on 32 bit and a `double`on 64 bit systems.